# Need to send notification when application was closed

Tags: flutter

I need to send a notification to the user when the app terminated by the user or by the system. Now I have a timer for 15 seconds and every time I schedule a 30-sec notification like this:

```
Timer doNotCloseTimer;

makeDoNotCloseNotification(){
  String notificationHeader = "App closed!";

  var androidChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
     // Android notification settings
  );
  var iOSChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
  var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(androidChannelSpecifics, iOSChannelSpecifics);

  var scheduledNotificationDateTime = DateTime.now().add(Duration(seconds: 30));
  if(doNotCloseTimer == null)
    doNotCloseTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 15), (timer) async {
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(NOTIFICATION_DO_NOT_CLOSE_ID);
      makeDoNotCloseNotification();
    });

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
      NOTIFICATION_DO_NOT_CLOSE_ID,
      notificationHeader,
      "",
      scheduledNotificationDateTime,
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: "DoNotClosePayload"
  );
}
```

App terminated with a timer and notification comes.
But there is a lot of problems, for some reason only in release mode when I can't understand what is going on. Sometimes timer doesn't work and the notification comes when the app is opened and in background. How to do it correctly?
Thanks.

UPD: AndroidManifest part
In <application> tag:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
```

And inside <manifest>

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Comment: did you add all the notifications plugin permissions in androidmanifest file ?

Comment: Yes, add to the post. I have the necessary permission and receiver. Sometimes it works okay, but sometimes there are issues